# Error in eval_tidy(pair$lhs, env = default_env) : object 'Var1' not found

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, geom-text

I am having trouble using case_when for customizing my labels in a ggplot inside a pipe chain.

I'm working with labbeled data but I made this reproducible data to show my error. Here's my code:

```
#data
padmin1<- data.frame(q0005_0001 = rep(c("Insuficiente1", "Poco Suficiente2","Regular3","Suficiente4","Muy Suficiente5")),5)

#Graphic
padmin1 %>% 
  rename(Var1=q0005_0001) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = "", y = X5, fill = fct_rev(ordered(Var1)))) +  
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 0.2) +
  geom_text(aes(label = X5), position = position_stack(vjust=0.5), colour= case_when(
    Var1 == "Insuficiente1" ~ "white",
    Var1 == "Poco Suficiente2" ~ "black",
    Var1 == "Regular3" ~ "black",
    Var1 == "Suficiente4" ~ "white",
    Var1 == "Muy Suficiente5" ~ "white",
    TRUE ~ "white"
  ) , fontface = "bold") +
  coord_flip() +
  labs(title= "La información brindada por la facultad le resultó...", caption = "Elaborado por SS, 2021") + 
  #Temas de colores
  theme(axis.title = element_blank(), 
        line = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent", color = NA),
        plot.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent", color = NA),
        legend.position = "bottom", 
        panel.border = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        legend.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent", linetype = "solid", colour = "transparent"),
        legend.box.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent", colour = "transparent"),
        axis.text = element_blank()) +
  scale_fill_manual("Leyenda", values = c("Insuficiente1"="#8A0000", "Poco Suficiente2"="#FFCD2F", "Regular3"="#DAA600", "Suficiente4"="#144D6C", "Muy Suficiente5"="#071C27"))
```

After running this code it appears the following error:

#Error in eval_tidy(pair$lhs, env = default_env) : object 'Var1' not found

Let me know what is wrong, i already tried puting `.$` before `Var1` in the `geom_text()` but is not working.

Comment: If you want to do the assignment this way: Move `colour=case_when(..` inside `aes()` and add `scale_color_identity`. For me it would be more natural to make use of `scale_color_manual` as you did with `fill`.

Comment: Hi stefan thanks for the answer, could you be a little more specific? maybe inserting a chunk of code for me to render it? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve your desired result move `colour=case_when(...` inside `aes()` and add `scale_color_identity`. However, instead of making use of a case_when I would suggest an `ifelse` + `grepl` as there are just two options, `black` and `white`.

Moreover, to the get right order of the labels you have to add `group=fct_rev(ordered(Var1))`. Otherwise the labels are "stacked" in a different order than the bars:

```r
#data
padmin1<- data.frame(q0005_0001 = rep(c("Insuficiente1", "Poco Suficiente2","Regular3","Suficiente4","Muy Suficiente5")),5)

library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)

#Graphic
padmin1 %>% 
  rename(Var1=q0005_0001) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = "", y = X5, fill = fct_rev(ordered(Var1)))) +  
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 0.2) +
  geom_text(aes(label = X5, 
                color = ifelse(grepl("^(P|R)", Var1), "black", "white"),
                group = fct_rev(ordered(Var1)) ), position = position_stack(vjust=0.5) , fontface = "bold") +
  scale_color_identity() +
  coord_flip() +
  labs(title= "La información brindada por la facultad le resultó...", caption = "Elaborado por SS, 2021") + 
  #Temas de colores
  theme(axis.title = element_blank(), 
        line = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent", color = NA),
        plot.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent", color = NA),
        legend.position = "bottom", 
        panel.border = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        legend.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent", linetype = "solid", colour = "transparent"),
        legend.box.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent", colour = "transparent"),
        axis.text = element_blank()) +
  scale_fill_manual("Leyenda", values = c("Insuficiente1"="#8A0000", "Poco Suficiente2"="#FFCD2F", "Regular3"="#DAA600", "Suficiente4"="#144D6C", "Muy Suficiente5"="#071C27"))
```

[image]

Comment: This is an incredible answer thanks stephan. You have help me make my graphics more automatic. Now i'm trying to automate the bar colors  because in my r code i use scale_fill_manual to detect every category and assign the color red, blue, yellow, etc. Do you know a formula to assign the legend colors depending of the order in the dataframe? first red, second light yellow, third dark yellow, fourth blue, fifth dark blue? maybe with grepl. If you figure it out let me know. Peace out